# Group geometry points according to spatial proximity

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have the following points in 3D space:

[image]

I need to *group* the points, according to `D_max` and `d_max`:

```
D_max = max dimension of each group
d_max = max distance of points inside each group
```

Like this:

[image]

The shape of the group in the above image looks like a box, but the shape can be anything which would be the output of the *grouping* algorithm.

---

I'm using Python and visualize the results with Blender. I'm considering using the [scipy.spatial.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) and calling its [query](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query) API, however, I'm not sure if that's the right tool for the job at hand. I'm worried that there might be a better tool which I'm not aware of. I'm curious to know if there is any other tool/library/algorithm which can help me.

---

As @CoMartel pointed out, there is [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) and also [HDBSCAN clustering](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan) modules which look like a good fit for this type of problems. However, as pointed out by @Paul they lack the option for max size of the cluster which correlates to my `D_max` parameter. I'm not sure how to add a max cluster size feature to DBSCAN and HDBSCAN clustering.

---

Thanks to @Anony-Mousse I watched [Agglomerative Clustering: how it works](https://youtu.be/XJ3194AmH40) and [Hierarchical Clustering 3: single-link vs. complete-link](https://youtu.be/VMyXc3SiEqs) and I'm studying [Comparing Python Clustering Algorithms](http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing_clustering_algorithms.html#dbscan), I feel like it's getting more clear how these algorithms work.

Comment: It looks like a DBScan could do a better job : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html

Comment: @CoMartel Thanks so much. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: There is also a derivative called HDBScan, with some differences that might be good for you

Comment: DBScan only considers `d_max` but not `D_max` (to stay in the parlance of this post). Also, I am not sure how well DBScan will work anyway, as most of the points seem to be on a grid, and hence most nearest neighbors will be equally far away.

Comment: @Paul Right. DBScan, has a not option for the max size of clusters. I'm not sure how to do a workaround.

Comment: If you do apply DBSCAN first, what is the maximum distance of points within a cluster (let's call it `D`)? How does that compare to your target `D_max`? You may find that that currently, `D >> D_max`, in which case you probably would just want to pre-cluster your points with DBSCAN, and then partition those clusters using some other algorithm to enforce your `D_max` criterion (which to me really seems more of a [packaging problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) than a clustering problem).

Comment: @Paul Right. Currently I'm playing around with `DBSCAN`, probably I'll be back with some questions. Thanks.

Comment: @CoMartel Can you please post your comments on DBSCAN and HDBSCAN as an answer so that I can accept it and close the question as answered. Your suggestion of those two algorithms actually solved my problem.

Comment: DBSCAN does not satisfy d_max either. Epsilon is not the max distance of points, but the maximum *step* size. Where points in the same cluster may be multiple steps apart, as long as each step is dense. The max distance can be much larger than this.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I didn't quite get how `d_max` and `eps` are related. I mean I didn't get how `eps` or *step* size work in DBSCAN. Is there any documentation which can help me to understand the *step* or `eps` concept? Thanks.

Comment: the key idea of DBSCAN is to join any overlapping eps-neighborhoods (that are "dense"). If you do this transitively, there is no upper bound on pairwise distances. Eps and d_max do *not* relate, as there is no d_max in DBSCAN.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I watched [Agglomerative Clustering: how it works](https://youtu.be/XJ3194AmH40 "Agglomerative Clustering: how it works") and [Hierarchical Clustering 3: single-link vs. complete-link](https://youtu.be/VMyXc3SiEqs "Hierarchical Clustering 3: single-link vs. complete-link") and I'm studying [Comparing Python Clustering Algorithms](http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing_clustering_algorithms.html#dbscan "Comparing Python Clustering Algorithms"), I feel like it's getting more clear. Thanks for your help. I actually mis-understood how these algorithms work.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Now, my understanding is that the DBSCAN `eps` is actually the distance at which we cut the dendrogram hierarchy.

Comment: DBSCAN corresponds to cutting the OPTICS plot at height epsilon, but not to HAC dendrograms. In particular, not to complete-linkage.

Comment: If you don't trust me, just run DBSCAN on 1-dim points 1..100, with eps=5 and minpts=5. You will get one cluster, much larger than eps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer :

You could use DBSCAN(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) or HDBSCAN.

Both these algorithm allow to group each point according to d_max (maximum distance between 2 points of the same dataset), but they don't take the maximum cluster size. The only way to limit the maximum size of a cluster is by reducing the `eps`parameter, which control the max distance between 2 points of the same cluster.

Comment: It seems I've not been clear : DBSCAN doesn't allow to control the group size indeed, but by changing the eps parameter, it will change the maximum distance between 2 points and (as a consequence), change the group size. But yes, this is not exactly what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use **hierarchical agglomerative clustering**.

If you use **complete linkage** you can control the maximum diameter of the clusters. The complete link is the maximum distance.

DBSCAN's epsilon parameter is *not* a maximum distance because multiple steps are joined transitively. Clusters *can* become much larger than epsilon!

Comment: I took a look at [sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html). It looks like what I need. I will give it a try with option `linkage=’complete’`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**DBSCAN clustering algorithm with the maximum distance of points inside each group extension**

You can use the DBSCAN algorithm recursively.

```
def DBSCAN_with_max_size(myData, eps = E, max_size = S):
     clusters = DBSCAN(myData, eps = E)
     Big_Clusters = find_big_clusters(clusters)
     for big_cluster in Big_Clusters:
         DBSCAN_with_max_size(big_cluster ,eps = E/2 ,max_size = S) //eps is something lower than E (e.g. E/2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try ☺